# Field of Solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I was reading [this](https://inspirehep.net/record/303287/), where in the very beginning I stumbled on the "particle in a solenoid field theme".
What's written in there is:

> The potentianl $\textbf{A}$ is chosen to be that of a solenoid field, 
>   $$
> A^a = -\frac{\epsilon^{ab}}{2\pi} \frac{\hat{x}^b}{\rho}\Phi(\rho)
> $$
>   where $\Phi(\rho)$ is a function of the radial coordinate $\rho$ which satisfies $\Phi(\rho) = \Phi_0 = \operatorname{const}$ when $\rho > \rho_0$ (outside the solenoid), leading to the magnetic field 
>   $$
> B = \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{\rho} \frac{d}{d\rho} \Phi(\rho)
> $$

This story is about particle on a plane and it's been said in the beginning that solenoid is thin. Yet I don't understand the first formula, can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting magnetic field that is stated is found because the first equation is a [vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential). I haven't read this paper specifically but it appears that the vector potential equation is in relativistic notation (simplified way of writing vectors). In context of this question we can perform the following in cylindrical coordinates

$$
B = \nabla \times A = \nabla \times -\frac{\epsilon^{ab}}{2\pi}\frac{\hat{x}^b}{\rho}\Phi(\rho)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{d}{d\rho}\Phi(\rho)
$$

Remember this curl was taken cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Addition: text was about 2D case, so if anyone has an interest 2D rotor should be calculated according to the rule v x w = e^{ab}v^a w^b, and it's a pseudo-scalar. e^{ab} is an anti-symmetric tensor.